# Site affected by malware

Tags: malware

Does anyone know of a site / service that provides an updated list of all sites which are known to be affected by some kind of malware?

Ie sites that get the Chrome/ Firefox malware popup (This site has been affected by malware!)

Comment: Bad luck with SU, stack exchange users can be a tough crowd. I don't think you'll find such listings made public for a number of reasons - such as not wanting to make it easy for people to get to the sites and not giving the malicious types an easy time of finding out what has been discovered. Depending on your use case, checking URLs with a tool like Alex suggested is your best bet.

Comment: @JohnC Yes, the API Alex suggested looks solid.

Comment: Strictly speaking your question doesn't really belong here since it doesn't directly relate to using a web application. That said, it isn't a good fit for SU or probably even Webmasters SE. Perhaps if you gave more of why you are looking. Badmouthing SU probably doesn't help either since many people here also contribute there.

Comment: Yea, many people just really go overboard with the "content curation"

Comment: The reason that the Stack Exchange network of sites are so useful is because we ruthlessly get rid of things that are off-topic. "Broken Windows" theory and all that. But now these comments have completely diverged from their purpose, which is to help improve the content of a post.

Comment: @AlEverett I'm sorry dude, but this was on topic. I'm looking for a website, api or app that gives me access to data I need to make decisions.  How in your left brained mind is that off topic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don’t know any (well known) site that does that, but there is [Google’s Safe Browsing API](https://developers.google.com/safe-browsing/) if you want to do something programmatically.

Answer (score 2):

Try the [StopBadware Clearinghouse](http://www.stopbadware.org/home/clearinghouse). That's probably where Google and Firefox are getting their information. There's not a list of the sites (at present there's nearly a million URLs in their database) but you can search for specific site URLs.